# Is $\pi (x)=\operatorname{R}(x)-\sum_{\rho}\operatorname{R}(x^{\rho})$ correct at all?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta-function

> It should be the case that, in some appropriate sense
> $$\pi (x)\sim \operatorname{Ri}(x)-\sum_{\rho}\operatorname{Ri}(x^{\rho}) \tag*{(4)}$$
> with $\operatorname{Ri}$ denoting the *Riemann function* defined:
> $$\operatorname{Ri}(x)=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{\mu (m)}{m}\operatorname{li}\left(x^{\frac{1}{m}}\right). \tag*{(5)}$$
> This relation $(4)$ has been called "exact" [in Ribenboim's *The New Book of Prime Number Records*], yet we could not locate a proof in the literature; such a proof should be nontrivial, as the conditionally convergent series involved are problematic. In any case relation $(4)$ is quite accurate, and furthermore the Riemann function $\operatorname{Ri}$ can be calculated efficiently (...) The sum in $(4)$ over **critical zeros** is not absolutely convergent, and furthermore the phases of the summands interact in a frightfully complicated way.

—from *Journal of Computational and Applied Mathematics by Borwein et al.*

> Of profound importance, Bernhard Riemann proved that the prime-counting function is exactly
> $$\pi (x)=\operatorname{R}(x)-\sum_{\rho}\operatorname{R}(x^{\rho})$$
> where
> $$\operatorname{R}(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu (n)}{n}\operatorname{li}\left(x^{\frac{1}{n}}\right),$$
> (...) $\rho$ indexes **every zero** of the Riemann zeta function, and $\operatorname{li}\left(x^{\frac{\rho}{n}}\right)$ is not evaluated with a branch cut but instead considered as $\operatorname{Ei}\left(\frac{\rho}{n}\ln x\right)$. Equivalently, if the trivial zeros are collected and the sum is taken **only over the non-trivial zeros** $\rho$ of the Riemann zeta function, then $\pi (x)$ may be written
> $$\pi (x)=\operatorname{R}(x)-\sum_{\rho}\operatorname{R}(x^{\rho})-\frac{1}{\ln x}+\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\frac{\pi}{\ln x}.$$

—from *Wikipedia's Prime counting function article* (before 30/7/2021)

**Questions:**

1. According to Borwein and Ribenboim, the index in $(4)$ should run only over **non-trivial zeros**. According to Wikipedia, the index in $(4)$ should run over **all zeros**. Wikipedia states that if the sum runs only over non-trivial zeros, then we add the $\ln$ and $\arctan$ terms, which is even more confusing. So what's true?
2. I'm pretty sure that Riemann did not prove the formula $(4)$. He only **proposed** a "weaker" form of it, namely
   $$\pi (x)=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{\mu (m)}{m}J\left(x^{\frac{1}{m}}\right)$$
   where
   $$J(x)=\operatorname{li}(x)-\sum_{\rho}\operatorname{li}\left(x^{\rho}\right)+\int_x^\infty \frac{dt}{t(t^2-1)\ln t}-\ln 2$$
   and where $\rho$ runs over all non-trivial zeros. The formula was proven by Mangoldt, not Riemann. The Wikipedia article is wrong in that historical fact, isn't it?
3. Even though the proof of $(4)$ is nowhere to be found in the literature, Raymond Manzoni provided a partial proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269997/two-representations-of-the-prime-counting-function/282848#282848). I call it partial because it is unknown whether the series converges at all: How could that be settled down?

*Note:* When I refer to the formula $(4)$ in this question, I assume $=$ instead of $\sim$.

**Riesel and Gohl**

Riesel and Gohl show in *Some Calculations Related to Riemann's Prime Number Formula* that
$$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu (n)}{n}\left(\int_{x^{\frac{1}{n}}}^\infty \frac{\mathrm dt}{t(t^2-1)\ln t}-\ln 2\right)=\frac{1}{2\ln x}\sum_{n=1}^N \mu (n)+\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\frac{\pi}{\ln x}+\epsilon (x,N)$$
where
$$\epsilon (x,N)=-\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{\mu (n)}{n}\left(\frac{1}{2}\ln\ln x+C\right)+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{\mu (n)\ln n}{n}+\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{\mu (n)}{n}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\pi k}\arctan\frac{\ln x}{n\pi k}$$
where
$$C=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\pi k}\arctan\frac{1}{\pi k}+\int_1^\infty \frac{\mathrm du}{u(e^{2u}-1)}-\ln 2+\frac{1}{2}.$$
Now, $\epsilon\to 0$ as $N\to\infty$.
If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu (n)=-2$, then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu (n)}{n}\int_{x^{\frac{1}{n}}}^\infty \frac{\mathrm dt}{t(t^2-1)\ln t}=\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\frac{\pi}{\ln x}-\frac{1}{\ln x}.$$

But this uses the zeta-regularized result $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu (n)=-2$. It is one way of assigning a finite value to a divergent sum, obtained by just plugging $s=0$ in
$$\frac{1}{\zeta (s)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu (n)}{n^s}.$$

In general, this assigning of values is arbitrary. There are lots of ways to do that. I don't understand how can this arbitrary choice produce an "empirically-correct" result about the distribution of prime numbers. In fact, the paper of Riesel and Gohl implies the mysterious formula
$$\pi (x)= \operatorname{R}(x)-\sum_{\rho}\operatorname{R}(x^{\rho})-\frac{1}{\ln x}+\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\frac{\pi}{\ln x}.$$
For the empirical results, see [here](http://www.primefan.ru/stuff/primes/table.html#theory).

**Questions [continued]:**

4. What makes zeta-regularization (or other regularizations producing the same value) the only regularization that seems to produce the "empirically-correct" result? Or is it the case that the result is ultimately wrong?

*Note*: $\operatorname{li}x$ is to be interpreted as the Cauchy principal value of $\operatorname{Ei}\ln x$.

This question has been on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3615529/is-pi-x-operatornamerx-sum-rho-operatornamerx-rho-correct-a) for some time, but it still doesn't have any answers, so I decided to post it here.

**Edit:**
The Wikipedia formula (before 30/7/2021)
$$\pi (x)= \operatorname{R}(x)-\sum_{\rho}\operatorname{R}(x^{\rho})-\frac{1}{\ln x}+\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\frac{\pi}{\ln x}$$
turned out to be a misinterpretation of Riesel and Gohl.

Comment: The trivial zeros contribution is simple enough that it can be expressed in closed form - that's the arctan and other terms you're seeing.

Comment: $(4)$ should be exact in the sense of distributions

Comment: Landau has a paper published in Ann. Ec. Norm., (3) 25, (1908) 399-442 with title something as "New proof of Riemann's formula for the number of prime numbers less than a limit", but I am translating this from my Spanish translation of the paper. In this paper Landau (with all the care to the detail that we all know) proves this formula. Showing in particular the convergence of the series of $\text{Li}(x^\rho)$ adequately ordered.

Comment: The end of the following Wolfram MathWorld article seems to imply an explicit formula for $\pi(x)$ derived from the explicit formula for $J(x)$ has never been proven to converge: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannPrimeCountingFunction.html.

Comment: @Wane The exact reference to the paper of Landau is: E. Landau, Nouvelle demonstration pour la formule de Riemann sur le nombre des nombres premiers inférieurs a une limite donnée et demonstration d'une formule plus générale pour le cas des nombres premiers d'une progression arithmétique, Ann. Ec. Norm. (3) 25, (1908) 399-442.

Comment: @juan I couldn't find the article. Do you have a link?

Comment: With respect to your question about $li(x)$, I believe the correct way to evaluate Riemann's explicit formula for the prime-power counting function $J(x)$ is as follows where $\rho$ represents a non-trivial zero of $\zeta(s)$ and the sum over $n$ represents the contribution of the trivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$: $J_o(x)=li(x)-\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{|\Im(\rho)|<K} Ei(\log\,(x)\,\rho)\right)-\log(2)-\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N Ei(-2\,n\,\log(x))\right)$.

Comment: @Wane Not, I have a copy from many years ago. But the French journals are usually in   NUMDAM   http://www.numdam.org  . Landau have also a German version of his paper. Neuer Beweis der Riemannschen Primzahlformel, Sitzunberichte der Königlich Preussischen Akademie der Wissenschaften zu Berlin, 1908, p. 737-745. But this I have not seen.

Comment: @Wane  Here it is the paper in French http://www.numdam.org/volume/ASENS_1908_3_25/

Comment: @juan I see. But even though I don't know the language, the paper you're referencing doesn't seem to get rid of the integral term (they end up with $\int_x^\infty \frac{dy}{y^{1-a}\log y\, (y^2-1)}$). However, getting rid of the integral is one of the main aspects of this question. The integral term "should" be able to be simplified to the "arctan" terms or something similar.

Comment: @juan This
$$f(x)=\operatorname{Li}(x)-\lim_{g\to\infty}\sum_{[???]}\{\operatorname{Li}(x^{\rho '})+\operatorname{Li}(x^{\rho ''})+\int_x^\infty \frac{dy}{y\log y\, (y^2-1)}$$
is the main formula of the paper, as far as I can tell ($f(x)=\sum_{p,m;\, p^m\lt x}\frac{1}{m}$). (Some parts are quite unreadable)

Comment: @juan The paper you're referencing doesn't seem to prove anything new.

Comment: @juan Well, maybe apart from the convergence of the series of $\operatorname{Li}(x^{\rho})$...

Comment: I believe $\int\limits_x^\infty\frac{1}{y\ \left(y^2-1\right) \log(y)}\ dy=-\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty } \text{Ei}(-2 n \log (x))$. I believe some authors use $\rho$ to indicate the entire set of zeta zeros (trivial as well as non-trivial) and combine the two sums in the formula I posted for $J_o(x)$ in an earlier comment into a single sum over $\rho$. Also the explicit formula for $J_o(x)$ only converges for $x>1$.

Comment: As for the empirical correctness of the zeta regularization, it kind of makes me think of Zipf's law for natural languages, which may be a clue that the Riemann zeta function accounts for some universal natural phenomenon, just like the normal distribution.

Comment: @Wane Landau proves the main formula of Riemann (you write it, except for a summand $-\log 2$). All the other formulas (when correctly written, I have not checked yours) follow relatively easy from this. As Steven Clark says, the formulas can be written in several equivalent forms, depending on how you treat the trivial zeros of zeta. Riesel and Gohl have a valuable simplification of this formulas. I translated to Spanish the paper of Landau in part to clarify the bad typing of the original. Understanding Landau and writing correctly his formulas in Latex.

Comment: @juan How does Riesel and Gohl formula follow from Riemann's? Their proof was based on assigning a finite value to a divergent series. Even Borwein stated that a proof should be nontrivial.

Comment: @Wane Riesel and Gohl never use $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(n)=-2$. Only say that to make the bound of the error it is preferable to use some $N$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^N \mu(n)=-2$. Such $N$ exist because the partial sums oscillates between positive and negative values.   But Riesel and Gohl objective was how to compute $\pi(x)$ with a bounded error using Riemann's formula.

Comment: @juan I see. I was confused by this webpage (http://www.primefan.ru/stuff/primes/table.html#theory) which states "... the last one is obvious if we allow generalized summation $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu (n)=\frac{1}{\zeta (0)}$"

Comment: In light of your latest edit, are you planning to fix the Wikipedia article?

Comment: @Emil Jeřábek The user vitamin d already told me he is going to edit the article today.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Preliminaries.* We will denote the slight modifications of the prime counting function and the prime power counting function with $\pi^*$ and $J^*$ respectively, which assume a halfway step at discontinuities. Furthermore we will denote the non-trivial zeros of the zeta function with $\rho$ and all zeros i.e. the trivial and non-trivial zeros with $\varrho$ in questions two to four.

Q1. It depends on what the meaning of $\sim$ in the statement $\pi^* (x)\sim \operatorname{Ri}(x)-\sum_{\rho}\operatorname{Ri}(x^{\rho})$ is. Putting convergence questions aside, which we will discuss in Q3, we indeed have an equality if the sum runs over all zeros of $\zeta$. If we omit the trivial zeros, the statement might still be correct, if $\sim$ denotes asymptotic equivalence since $\sum_n\operatorname{Ri}(x^{-2n})=o(1).$ This is because
$$\left\lvert\lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_n\sum_m \frac{\mu(m)}{m}\operatorname{li}(x^{-2n/m})\right\rvert \leqslant \lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_n\sum_m \frac{1}{m}\left\lvert\operatorname{li}(x^{-2n/m})\right\rvert\overset{\text{(Tonelli)}}{=}0.$$

Q2. "Proposed" might not be the best fitting word. Riemann showed and proved essential ideas of his, while leaving out certain steps, which caused a certain lack of rigor. Hence, Riemann's proof was not complete. Quoting Edwards, p.38, 1.19 QUESTIONS UNRESOLVED BY RIEMANN:

> Riemann evidently believed that he had given a proof of the product formula for $\zeta(s)$, but, at least from the reading of the paper given above, one cannot consider his proof to be complete, and, in particular, one must question Riemann's estimate of the number of roots $\rho$ in the range $\{0 < \operatorname{Im} \rho < T\}$ on which this proof is based. It was not until 1893 that Hadamard proved the product formula, and not until 1905 that von Mangoldt proved the estimate of the number of roots in $\{0 < \operatorname{Im} \rho < T\}$.

Q3. We want to prove that $\pi^*(x)=\operatorname{R}(x)-\sum_{\varrho} \operatorname{R}(x^{\varrho})$ follows from $\pi^*(x)=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(m)}{m}J^*(x^{1/m})$. Define $\pi_X^*\colon \mathbb R_{>1}\to\mathbb N$ as $$x\mapsto\sum_{m\leqslant X}\frac{\mu(m)}{m}J^*(x^{1/m}),$$
where $X>1$. If $X>\log_2(x)$, then $\pi_X^*(x)=\pi^*(x)$, since $J^*(x)=0$ for $x<2$. After applying Möbius inversion on $J^*$ we get that for all $X>\log_2(x)$
$$\pi^*(x)=\sum_{m\leqslant X}\frac{\mu(m)}{m}\operatorname{li}(x^{1/m})-\sum_{\varrho}\sum_{m\leqslant X}\frac{\mu(m)}{m}\operatorname{li}(x^{\varrho/m})-\log 2\sum_{m\leqslant X}\frac{\mu(m)}{m}.$$
We were able to change the order of summation involving the conditional convergent series since the series over $m$ is finite. Now the idea is not to look at the case $X\to\infty$ separately. There exists an $N\in\mathbb N$ for every $X>1$ so that $\pi^*_X(x)=\pi^*_N(x)$. The sequence $(\pi_N^*)_{N\in\mathbb N}$ converges since it is Cauchy.

Q4. Riesel's and Göhl's objective was to find an approximation and not an exact form of the last two terms of $\pi_N(x)$, $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu (n)}{n}\left(\int_{x^{\frac{1}{n}}}^\infty \frac{\mathrm dt}{t(t^2-1)\ln t}-\ln 2\right)$. The integral is equivalent to $\sum_m\operatorname{li}(x^{-2n/m})$. They eventually showed that it is equal to $\frac{1}{2\ln x}M(N)+\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\frac{\pi}{\ln x}+\epsilon (x,N),$ where $M$ denotes the Mertens function and $\epsilon$ is an error term, which tends to zero as $N\to\infty$. In order to make the calculation more efficient they replace the Mertens function with $-2$ and argue on page 979 as follows:

> It is thus advantageous to choose such a value of $N$ that the sums $g_k$ become comparatively small. It also is advantageous to have $\sum_1^N\mu(n) = -2$ at the same time, since (32) then has the order of magnitude only $= O((\log x)^{-3})$ instead of $O((\log x)^{-1})$.

Here no zeta regularization was used. The triple sums in the error term are dependent on $g_k$. There exist infinitely many $N$ such that $M(N)=-2$. This immediately follows from the bounds $\liminf~M(n)/\sqrt n < -1.009$ and $\limsup~M(n)/\sqrt n > 1.06$, which were used to disprove the Mertens conjecture.

Comment: So the Wikipedia formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) $\pi _0(x)=\operatorname{R}(x)-\sum_{\rho}\operatorname{R}(x^{\rho})-\frac{1}{\log x}+\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\frac{\pi}{\log x}$ is incorrect?

Comment: Regarding Q2 – I didn't consider an incomplete proof to be a proof, but it is understandable that someone prefers to consider incomplete "proofs" to be proofs.

Comment: This was not mentioned in my post but it is related: $\operatorname{R}(x)=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(\ln x)^n}{nn!\, \zeta (n+1)}$. Using $\operatorname{R}(x^{\varrho})=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(\ln (x^{\varrho}))^n}{nn!\, \zeta (n+1)}$ leads to wrong results. Why is simply using $\operatorname{R}(x^{\varrho})=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(\varrho\ln x)^n}{nn!\, \zeta (n+1)}$ enough to fix the issue?

Comment: Riesel and Göhl replaced $M(N)$ with $-2$ for all $N$, which results in a loss of an equality. However the error terms are very small: For $N=154$, the error  $\lvert p+\epsilon\rvert$ is less than $1.2\cdot10^{-4}$.

Comment: After calculating the Inverse Mellin transform of $\log\zeta$ the result of the second term of $J^*$ is $\operatorname{Ei}(\rho \log x)$ and not $\operatorname{Ei}( \log(x^\rho))$, which can be converted into the Gram series with the well-known series representation of $\operatorname{Ei}$.